# Python edit line containing specific characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, readlines

I was wondering if there is a way to edit those lines of a file that contain certain characters.
Something like this:

```
file.readlines()
for line in file:
    if 'characters' in line:
       file[line] = 'edited line'
```

If it matters: I'm using python 3.5

Comment: You can also use `linecache` module in python. Search it,  but i believe the first answer will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
lines = file.readlines()
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if 'characters' in line:
        lines[index] = 'edited line'
```

You can't edit the file directly, but you can write out the modified `lines` over the original (or, safer, write to a temporary file and renamed once you've validated it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` to create a temporary file object and write your lines in it the use `shutil` module to replace the temp file with your preceding file.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil

tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
with open(file_name) as infile,tempfile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'characters' in line:
            tempfile.write('edited line')
        else:
            tempfile.write(line)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, file_name)
```